# Uncomfortable variability of MO reputation

Tags: support, reputation

Some of my reputation data on MathOverflow got changed in a past couple of days back and forth twice. In particular, my reputation went up 200 points, then back to the previous state, then up by 160 points, then again to the original state. Any explanation? (I have not a clue of what's going on).

I apologize if there were similar questions posted in the past weak (or two?). Then let me see a link, please.

Comment: There was a book on that by Milan Kundera.

Comment: @Will, would you share the title with us?

Comment: Apparently i was slightly off about the title, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Unbearable_Lightness_of_Being

Comment: @Will, that's what I suspected :-) (There is a certain melodic similarity between the two titles).

Answer (score 9):

This is due to voting irregularities that have been detected and corrected by the software. Apologies for the confusion. The users responsible for this have been contacted privately and asked to cease causing these irregularities.

Comment: As a side note, the reputation change breakdown is available [in the user profile](http://mathoverflow.net/users/8385/wlodzimierz-holsztynski?tab=reputation).

Comment: Thank you FGD and AL. "Reputation" is supposed to be some harmless entertainment, a trivia item. Instead, it became unpleasant.

Comment: @WlodzimierzHolsztynski: I agree. Unfortunately, like in many games, some players get overly enthusiastic and the referees must step in...

Comment: François, just out of curiosity (and don't answer if it may cause any problem): what kind of voting irregularities are there on this site? Is that people creating many accounts to vote several times?

Comment: @Joël I think the biggest problem is people creating sock puppet accounts to vote themselves up.  I can't recall a case that involved anything else, but perhaps there's one I don't know of.

Comment: There have also been occasional spots of nuisance downvoting (thankfully few).

Comment: In this case it sounds like someone systematically going through Wlodzimierz's answers and upvoting them without reading them. I believe that there are bots running to detect these kinds of anomalies and reverse such votes.